# Android Change WiFi hostname programmatically

Tags: android, android-networking

I am building  one App. It requires to change the Hostname at run time. Is it possible to do this through android code?

I know this

```
  setprop net.hostname someabcdefgh
```

but I want to change this at run time. Is there any APIs available to change the Hostname?

Answer (score 0):

To change the hostname (device name) you have to use the terminal (as root):

For Eclair (2.1): echo MYNAME > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname

For Froyo (2.2): (works also on most 2.3) setprop net.hostname MYNAME

Then restart your wi-fi. To see the change, type uname -a

some devices needs reboot for work!